# Generate all permutations of a list including diferent sizes and repeated elements

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, permutation

I wanted to create the function `genAllSize ::[a] -> [[a]]`, that receives a list `l` and generates all the lists sorted by size that can be built with the elements of the list `l`;  i.e.

```
> genAllSize [2,4,8] 
[[],[2],[4],[8],[2,2],[4,2],[8,2],[2,4],[4,4],[8,4],[2,8],[4,8],[8,8],[2,2,2],[4,2,2],[8,2,2], ...
```

How would you do it? I came up with a solution using permutations from `Data.List` but I do not want to use it.

Comment: `filterM (\_ -> [False, True]) [2,4,8]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That doesn't select with replacement.

Comment: @chepner: aarghh, I missed that part :(

Comment: That solution does not take in account the possibility of repeated numbers. I did not want to post my solution because it was pretty ugly tho... I even came up with a solution without permutations and it's pretty ugly too

Comment: `genAllSize x = concat(iterate (\z -> genAllSize' z x) [[]]) where genAllSize' l li = foldl (\t i -> t++(map(\s -> s++[i]) l ) ) [ ] li `

Comment: The solution using `concat` and `iterate` is almost not ugly. Can you see a way to replace the `foldl` with an invocation of `concatMap` that accomplishes the same general purpose? Can you see that `i:s` accomplishes the same general purpose as `s++[i]` but in a different order and much more efficiently? This general approach will eventually run into efficiency trouble because its memory use grows fairly quickly, but it's otherwise fairly reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

- Given an input list `xs`, select a prefix of that in a non deterministic way
- For each element in the prefix, replace it with any element of `xs`, in a non deterministic way

Result:

```
> xs = [2,4,8]
> inits xs >>= mapM (const xs)
[[],[2],[4],[8],[2,2],[2,4],[2,8],[4,2],[4,4],[4,8],[8,2],[8,4],
[8,8],[2,2,2],[2,2,4],[2,2,8],[2,4,2],[2,4,4],[2,4,8],[2,8,2],
[2,8,4],[2,8,8],[4,2,2],[4,2,4],[4,2,8],[4,4,2],[4,4,4],[4,4,8],
[4,8,2],[4,8,4],[4,8,8],[8,2,2],[8,2,4],[8,2,8],[8,4,2],[8,4,4],
[8,4,8],[8,8,2],[8,8,4],[8,8,8]]
```

Comment: why is it finite?

Comment: @karakfa We only involve finite lists above. `xs` is finite, so `inits xs` is finite, and `>>=` loops over a finite number of finite prefixes. `mapM` loops over each element (finitely many), and replaces them with an element taken from `xs` (finite).

Comment: This doesn’t actually use the elements of the results of `inits`, just their lengths, so you could write this a bit more explicitly (albeit less elegantly imo) as `join [sequence $ take n $ repeat xs | n <- [0..length xs]]`. Also it’s worth knowing that `mapM (const xs)` = `sequence . fmap (const xs)` = `sequence . (xs <$)`; the expression `x <$ y` is handy for replacing all elements in the container `y` with `x` while retaining its shape, or running an action `y`, discarding its result, and returning `x` (where you might otherwise write `y *> pure x`).

Comment: I don't think you're getting all the lists the question asks for. Daniel Wagner's answer seems more on point.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Will Ness's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157534/generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-including-diferent-sizes-and-repeated-elemen#comment93381293_53247900)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers seem sort of complicated. I'd do it this way:

```
> [0..] >>= flip replicateM "abc"
["","a","b","c","aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc","aaa","aab",...
```

Comment: That does seem rather straightforward.

Comment: a sidenote, `replicateM n = sequence . replicate n`.

Comment: Like my solution, yours needs a special case to avoid looping on the empty list, and (less obviously) it wants a special case to avoid incrementing unary numbers the wrong way around when passed a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I guess you a need a lazy infinite list of cycling subsequences. One naive way could be like

```
Prelude> take 100 $ nub . subsequences . cycle $ [2,4,8]
[[],[2],[4],[2,4],[8],[2,8],[4,8],[2,4,8],[2,2],[4,2],[2,4,2],[8,2],[2,8,2],[4,8,2],[2,4,8,2],[4,4],[2,4,4],[8,4],[2,8,4],[4,8,4],[2,4,8,4],[2,2,4],[4,2,4],[2,4,2,4],[8,2,4],[2,8,2,4],[4,8,2,4],[2,4,8,2,4],[8,8],[2,8,8],[4,8,8],[2,4,8,8],[2,2,8],[4,2,8],[2,4,2,8],[8,2,8],[2,8,2,8],[4,8,2,8],[2,4,8,2,8],[4,4,8],[2,4,4,8],[8,4,8],[2,8,4,8],[4,8,4,8],[2,4,8,4,8],[2,2,4,8],[4,2,4,8],[2,4,2,4,8],[8,2,4,8],[2,8,2,4,8],[4,8,2,4,8],[2,4,8,2,4,8],[2,2,2],[4,2,2],[2,4,2,2],[8,2,2],[2,8,2,2],[4,8,2,2],[2,4,8,2,2],[4,4,2],[2,4,4,2],[8,4,2],[2,8,4,2],[4,8,4,2],[2,4,8,4,2],[2,2,4,2],[4,2,4,2],[2,4,2,4,2],[8,2,4,2],[2,8,2,4,2],[4,8,2,4,2],[2,4,8,2,4,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and highly efficient option:

```
genAllSize [] = [[]]
genAllSize [a] = iterate (a:) []
genAllSize xs =
  [] : [x:q|q<-genAllSize xs,x<-xs]
```

(Thanks to Will Ness for a small but very nice simplification.)

This solution takes advantage of the fact that a valid solution list is either empty or an element of the argument list consed onto a shorter valid solution list. Unlike Daniel Wagner's solution, this one doesn't resort to counting. My tests suggest that it performs extremely well under typical conditions.

Why do we need a special case for a one-element list? The general case performs extremely badly for that, because it maps over the same list over and over with no logarithmic slowdown.

But what's the deal with that call to `genAllSizes` with the very same argument? Wouldn't it be better to save the result to increase sharing?

```
genAllSize [] = [[]]
genAllSize xs = p
  where
    p = [] : [x:q|q<-p,x<-xs]
```

Indeed, on a theoretical machine with unlimited constant-time memory, this is optimal: walking the list takes worst-case O(1) time for each cons. In practice, it's only a good idea if a great many entries will be realized and retained. Otherwise, there's a problem: most of the list entries will be retained indefinitely, dramatically increasing memory residency and the amount of work the garbage collector needs to do. The non-bold sharing version above still offers *amortized* O(1) time per cons, but it needs very little memory (logarithmic rather than linear).

#### Examples

```
genAllSize "ab" =
 ["","a","b","aa","ba"
 ,"ab","bb","aaa","baa"
 ,"aba","bba","aab","bab"
 ,"abb","bbb","aaaa",...]

genAllSize "abc" =
  ["","a","b","c","aa","ba"
  ,"ca","ab","bb","cb","ac"
  ,"bc","cc","aaa","baa"
  ,"caa","aba","bba","cba"
  ,"aca",...]
```

#### An explicit option

You can also use two accumulators:

```
genAllSize [] = [[]]
genAllSize [a] = iterate (a:) []
genAllSize (x:xs) = go ([], []) where
  go (curr, remain) = curr : go (step curr remain)
  step [] [] = ([x], [xs])
  step (_:ls) ((r:rs):rss) =
    (r:ls, rs:rss)
  step (_:ls) ([] : rs) =
    (x : ls', xs : rs')
    where
      !(ls', rs') = step ls rs
```

This version keeps track of the current "word" and also the remaining available "letters" in each position. The performance seems comparable in general, but a bit better with regard to memory residency. It's also much harder to understand!

Comment: perhaps also, simply, `genAllSize xs = p
  where
    p = [] : [x:q|q<-genAllSize xs,x<-xs]` ? Also, I wonder, does the version with the flipped ordering really performs badly? Have you tested, perchance?

Comment: Ooh, you're almost certainly right about the shorter version. What do you mean about the flipped ordering?

Comment: @WillNess, the need for a special case for singletons makes me wonder if there's a slightly better way that doesn't need one. Haven't found it yet.

Comment: Ah, but that actually makes a lot of sense. Efficient counting in unary looks very different from efficient counting in another base, and we don't have the option of using a segmented system.

Comment: re: flipped ordering: it would be the `genAllSize xs = p where p = [] : [x:q|x<-xs,q<-genAllSize xs]`. but testing it with `xs = [1..3]`, it produces just 1s... facepalm. :)

Comment: "counting in unary looks very different" indeed. In unary, the only possible digit value is zero, and 0000000 is still a zero. :) So indeed it's a very special case.

Comment: @WillNess, huh? The only digit value is 1, and all carries propagate to the end.

Comment: the highest digit value allowed in base n is n-1, no?

Comment: @WillNess, yes, but what's called unary is quite different, as you surely know. The usual algorithm for incrementing a base-k number will work just fine for incrementing a unary representation (all 1s except for leading 0s, all places worth 1), but it'll be a lot less efficient than `snoc 1`.

Comment: I was overloading the meaning by using it as "base-1", with the word "digit". so it means that counting with sticks, or list elements, is not in *any* base, i.e. very special. I should've been clearer with my wording perhaps. was intending the smiley to show my half-joking intent.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the elements in a different order within each length than your example, but it meets the definition of the text of your question. Changing the order is easy - you have to replace `<*>` with a slightly different operator of your own making.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

rinvjoin :: Applicative both => both a -> both (both a)
rinvjoin = fmap pure

extendBranches options branches = (<|>) <$> options <*> branches
singletonBranchExtensions = rinvjoin

genAllSize [] = []
genAllSize xs = join <$> iterate (extendBranches extensions) $ initialBranches
  where extensions = singletonBranchExtensions xs
        initialBranches = pure empty
```

Comment: indeed. But I'm going to leave it because I get confused by the myriad of maximally refined concepts and I bet others do too.

Comment: My current solution has a problem that it keeps looking for branch extensions forever for genAllSize [] but where there's a finite answer, the list should be finite, really

Comment: `genAllSize xs = join $ iterate (liftA2 (<|>) (pure <$> xs)) (pure empty)` is write-only, though. Mine needs to be expanded out into more explicit definitions as it is, removing some can't be right.

Comment: It's not supposed to do what chi's answer is doing, chi's answer isn't correct

Comment: [2,2,2,2] is a list made from some combination of elements from [2,4,8] and yet chi's answer doesn't include it in the output list. My answer correctly includes it.

Comment: if you mean the sizes should be infinite, chi's code can be tweaked into `inits [1..] >>= mapM (const xs)`.

Comment: `inits (repeat ()) >>= mapM (const xs)` would be a better tweak for chi's answer because the seed structure explicitly has no content and that carries useful meaning.

Comment: consider `\xs -> concat $ iterate (liftA2 (:) xs) [[]]`, or `\xs -> concat $ iterate (map (:) xs <*>) [[]]` as your code's rewrite.

Comment: @Will Ness, only a mathematician could understand that and I bet they'd need to attend a conference presentation to do it, why remove the cues for the human leaving in place only what the computer uses? If that's a positive direction then you could compile my code and paste the raw machine code as a better alternative.

Comment: @Will Ness, I agree concat might be better than join because we want to explicitly retain the growth-based ordering and not leave it up to the datatype. I didn't do that to begin with because I like to practice retaining both descriptiveness and generality.